# Trying to get get_long_long to work in credit.c cs50

Tags: c, cs50

I been doing some research through stack overflow and also through the cs50 reference library.

The reference library states the obvious. Basically that get_long_long can be used, but that its being deprecated for get_long. Idk when, but that's what it says.

Stack Overflow has similar questions, but no one is answering what I am trying to find the answer for.

I have posted two pictures to show you what my code looks like and the error message I am receiving.

For some reason it is giving me this error saying that the implicit declaration is invalid, but I have the cs50.h library included at the top, so i'm a little confused.

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code

Comment: Why not? Just curious why you're saying not to post a picture of code. Wouldn't posting a picture of code help you better understand my problem?

Comment: See this: [mcve]. Images of code can't be copy/pasted and are hard for people using screen readers and text browsers. Instead, paste your code from your editor and [format it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Copy that...makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a function for which the compiler has not seen a declartion of yet. IE, you havent included it properly with the proper header files. I would check your includes and ensure that you have properly included the header file that contains the function. Alternatively, you can declare it before use above main if this is a local function. But it seems as though its part of the cs50 package, I would make sure you have that package in your include section or add a relative path to it if you can locate it on your system.

Comment: Yea, this file has the #include <stdio.h> and the #include <cs50.h> already attached to it. That's why I was a  little confused.